# Content overflow extending page height rather than defaulting to scroll

Tags: html, css

Video showcasing my problem: https://streamable.com/w0h3yn

Webpage: [ganznz.github.io/todo-list/dist/](https://ganznz.github.io/todo-list/dist/)

I'm having some trouble with my webpage where if the screen is around the width of a mobile screen, the content will overflow and become taller than the overlay (green see-through div) that's in-front of it, which I don't want. I have linked a video that shows my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding:

```
overflow: auto
```

to the css of your main content, which I believe is your class .main-content-container